# DurandalJS: activate() callback inside composition not running after route parameter change

Tags: javascript, durandal

Here's my setup:

- shell.js (includes main router)
- shell.html
- **offices**

  - shell.js (includes child router)
  - shell.html
  - sidebar.js
  - sidebar.html
  - **employees**

    - index.html
    - index.js

The main shell includes a route to the office page, which includes a list of employees that are part of that office:

```
{ route: 'offices/:id', moduleId: 'offices/shell' }
```

The sub-shell includes a composition that points to the sidebar for the office page.

```
<aside data-bind="compose: { model:'offices/sidebar', view:'offices/sidebar' }"></aside>
```

The problem is that the activate callback inside sidebar.js only runs when I first load the page and not when the id parameter of the route changes.

So when I change from `offices/12` to `offices/15` the only thing that runs is the activate callback inside offices/shell.js and the one inside employees/index.js.

Is there a way to reactivate the composition?

Thanks!

Comment: If the sidebar is a singleton then of course it wouldn't reactivate on route change.  Consider passing some object into the sidebar when you are activating the new route or whatever.

Comment: No, I return the sidebar as a function. How can I do that?